# Is there a case where an int-member is guaranteed to be zero-initialized?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14

I have read multiple discussions and C++ reference articles and I am still not sure.

Consider this:

```
class Foo
{
    int m;
};
```

Is `m` guaranteed to be zero in any of these cases?

- A) `auto foo = new Foo;`
- B) `auto foo = new Foo();`
- C) `auto foo = new Foo{};`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, in both (B) and (C) it will be zero. In (A) it's uninitialized.

If you add a custom default constructor to `Foo` (unless you `=default` it in the class body), then the behavior will be the same in all 3 cases: `m` will only be initialized if you initialize it explicitly.